# htaccess rewrite url to clean

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently I have this code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /l/index\.php\?\S*mp3=\S* [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bmp3=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html? [R=301,L]
```

And honestly? I am probably doing this all wrong so by all means take turns laughing at me but I have only had to use rewrite rules once before this so I am still learning and having a hard time at that.

I am trying to turn my nasty url that looks like the one displayed below.

```
http://dl.example.com/stream/index.php?a=Song+Artist&s=Song+Name&mp3=http://www.example.com/mp3embed-ep0v3t1lvsah.mp3
```

Broken down.

```
http://dl.example.com/stream/index.php?a=&s=&mp3=
```

into something that looks clean and sleek like this.

```
http://dl.example.com/ep0v3t1lvsah.html
```

Any help is very much appreciated as I said I am extremely new to `.htaccess` so being as informational as possible in your answer would be amazing!

Comment: @anubhava No sir.. it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Well your target shorter URL can't work because you are not using `a=Song+Artist&s=Song+Name` information in shorter URL